# After Eclipse upgrade existing projects are not associated with svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have upgraded my Eclipse to Indigo. After that I try to open my workspace, now some projects are associated with svn and some are not. (I have downloaded subclipse plugin also) I tried delete project and re-add it. But still it is not associated with svn. These projects are originally checkout from svn. How to re-associate these projects to svn? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it seems to be something common ... did you search in FAQs from eclipse website?

Comment: @memosdp I thought this is happening only to my local. After searching it seems like common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this: Select your project: Right Click & select Team: Select Share Project & follow the instructions. Either it will automatically connect your project to the appropriate project of svn (based on some .svn files) or it will ask you to choose appropriate project from svn.

Comment: When I do Right Click & select Team: Select Share Project, it shows svn cvs. If I click svn then I am getting an error "Unable to load default SVN Client".

Comment: Yes "Unable to load default SVN Client"

Comment: @MahendranA check the installation of the `svn` in your system

Comment: It is message box with only this error. No additional details.

Comment: After re-installing the subeclipse plugin it worked. Thanks for helping me out.